# Alternative Definitions of Complete Theories

Tags: logic

I'm reading Manin et al's "A Course in Mathematical Logic for Mathematicians". There is a definition of a complete theory that I can't square with others I've previouly read. I'll give the relevant definitions below:

Let L1 be the class of first-order languages. Let L be a language in L1. Let $\phi$ be an interpretation of L. Let $T_{\phi}L$ be the set of $\phi$-true formulas [i.e., what I refer to as a theory above], where a $\phi$-true formula is a formula that, given an interpretation, is true for all elements of the universe of discourse that we could assign to the free variables in the formula. The set $T_{\phi}L$ is in fact complete, meaning that for any closed formula P, either P or $\neg$P lies in $T_{\phi}L$.

Now, this sounds like the definition of syntactic completion, except that syntactic completion says that any formula or its negation is provable, and first-order logic is not syntactically complete--if I understand the incompleteness theorem at a layman's level. I haven't found anything to backup the assertion that any formula of a first-order language or its negation is true, nor a definition of this as completeness, so I'm reaching out here.

Comment: The incompleteness theorem has nothing to do with this.

Comment: The result is trivial: your set $T_\phi L$ is the set of all first-order formulas true in the interpretation $\phi$. For each first-order formula $P$, the interpretation either makes $P$ true or makes $P$ false and thus $\lnot P$ true. So either $P$ or $\lnot P$ is in $T_\phi L$. The statement isn't saying that first-order logic is negation complete (you're right it isn't).

Comment: Well, I just got 2 different answers, so I'm going with @symplectomorphic's unless Andres can provide more detail.

Comment: Our comments are unrelated. Andres is pointing out that you don't seem to know what "the incompleteness theorem" means, because it has nothing to do with whether or not first-order logic is negation complete; that theorem says the first-order theory of Peano arithmetic isn't negation complete.

Comment: Ok, I must have missed that qualifier earlier.

Comment: See [Completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)) for different uses of the same term.

Comment: Usually, we say that a "logic" (axioms + rules) is *complete* if it proves **all** valid formulas with respect to the corersponding semantics. E.g. classsical proposiotional calculus and predicate calculus are complete.

Comment: The "completeness" referred to by Manin is *negation completeness* with respect to an interpretation $\phi$. Example, for the f-o language of *arithmetic* and with respect to the "standard" interpretation based on the domain $\mathbb N$, we have that - obviously - for every closed formula $P$, either $P$ is *true* in $\mathbb N$ or $\lnot P$ is.

Comment: The relation with Godel's Incompleteness Th, is exactly that the "axiomatic" apparatus is **not** complete for that theory: i.e. tehre is a closed formula $G$ such that neither $G$ nor $\lnot G$ is derivable with f-o predicate calculus from f-o Peano's axioms.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, that's the definition I am used to as well. I think I the second half of my question related to me confusing the difference between statements that are true under all interpretations and those that are true under some interpretations, but not others. I didn't realize syntactic completeness referred to the decideability of statements that are true in a given interpretation, while semantic completeness referred to statements that are true in every interpretation (i.e., are valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that by

> where a $\phi$-true formula is a formula that, given **an** interpretation, is true for all elements of the universe of discourse that we could assign to the free variables in the formula.

you actually meant

> where a $\phi$-true formula is a formula that, given **the** interpretation, is true for all elements of the universe of discourse that we could assign to the free variables in the formula.

With that said there is nothing wrong with $T_\phi(L)$ being complete.

Indeed the only closed formulas in $T_\phi(L)$ are those which are true in the interpretation $\phi$ and it can be proved by the definition of the semantics for first-order logic languages that every **closed** formula is either true or false once you fix an interpretation, hence either it will belong to $T_\phi(L)$ or its negation will do.

The fact that $T_\phi(L)$ is complete does not imply in any way that the first-order logic (of language $L$) is complete.
In particular $T_\phi(L)$ is not the set of logic formulas which hold in every possible $L$-structure, that is, *by the completeness theorem*, the set of all formulas provable by first-order logic's inference rules.

So there is no problem with the incompleteness theorems here.